# Are interned strings eligible for garbage collection in Java 8?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

I came across the following text in Daniel Liang's latest book on Java programming (page 386, 10 th ed.):

> Does the following code change the contents of the string?
>
> ```
> String s = "Java";
>
> s = "HTML";
> ```
>
> The answer is no. .... **The first String object still exists after the assignment**, but it can no longer be accessed, because variable s now points to the new object, as shown in Figure 10.15.

Based on the above text, it seems that the author's opinion is that the string object "Java" is not garbage collected, even if it is not referenced any more. I know there have been some change in the storage location of interned strings in Java. Remember that the above book is dealing with Java SE 8.

But according to Java garbage collector, unused objects (objects that are no longer referenced) are automatically garbage collected.

So which case is the actual case for Java SE 8?

Comment: I don't think the author is claiming that strings can't be GC'ed; that statement is informally correct, and one might see it stated for other (non-string) types as well.

Comment: The _class_ as a whole, in its _code_, still carries a reference to that string literal.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are interned strings, but not all interned strings are string literals.

String literals are held alive by the classes in which they are defined which in turn are held alive by instances and classloaders. You need class-unloading for them to become eligible for GC.

Interning strings on the other hand only guarantees that if `string1.equals(string2)` then `string1.intern() == string2.intern()`. This particular definition allows interned strings to be garbage-collected because `oldInternedString != newInternedString` is not observable since there cannot be a reference to `oldInternedString` if it has been garbage-collected. So the string interning table *can* be (but is not required) implemented as a table of weak references, which allows them to be GCed.

Answer (score 0):

The author's point doesn't really have much to do with garbage collection.  The fact that the object will be garbage collected at some point in the future does not contradict the assertion that it still exists after the assignment.  He isn't saying that it will exist forever, just that the assignment does not alter the original object.

Comment: But he already introduced garbage collection in earlier chapter 7 for arrays and in chapter 9 for general objects. So when I read the above context for Strings in Chapter 10, it sounds confusing to me. Regardless of the text in that book, could you answer my question?

Comment: I think you are right in that the object will be garbage collected.  I just disagree with your assertion that the author's opinion is that the string object "Java" is not garbage collected.  The fact that he states the object is unchanged by the new assignment does not mean that it won't be garbage collected at some point.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: My pleasure.  I can certainly see where this would be confusing the way it was written in the book.